# Magento PWA Studio Performance Optimization Tips

Tags: php, database, magento2.3.3, apache, pwa-studio

i try to search for similar topics online but not found any good one to cover magento side optimizations and configs and the server side ones ..

as per magento side :
- Need to confirm that FPC need to be disabled and if any other caching is not needed .
- in my case i notice that running magento in developer mode and production mode have similar performance , production should provide better speed , right ?

as per a production website running PWA Studio , any tips to improve the performance to best possible ?

Comment: Did you find any answer?